# How to properly adjust unit dimensions for exporting to 3rd party program

Tags: export, dimensions

I am attempting to use blender with armorsmith and I am testing the dimensions of shapes before I design something large.

I have a  rectangle that is 2 x 2 x 8 inches or 50.8 x 50.8 x 203.2mm. I believe I have set the grid units correctly:
[image]

When I export an an obj file and load into armorsmith the dimensions seem to be WAY off. Its possible I need to contact someone that knows armorsmith but I am guessing the issue might be with blender as that part wasnt as straight forward.

When I import the obj file into armorsmith I get a warning that the dimensions are too small:
[image]

Its not until I scale the size by 1,000 that it seems the shape is the correct size, which would mean the dimentions exported would be closer to .0508 x .0508 x .2032mm:

[image]

Maybe im doing some horrible unit conversions, or maybe im doing something wrong in blender >_< Any ideas? (the model is scaled/sized using mm values as well). Thank you so much for taking the time to look at this

Comment: Ok this isn't an issue on either end don't worry. You are showing us the scale which will be applied/ set to 1 when exported. The dimensions stay the same.

Comment: So the unit scale in the first picture is for exporting? but at a value of 1, wouldnt that keep the dimensions of the shape(same picture) the same? Think I might be missing what you are saying

Comment: As simple as I can say it.
Dimensions stay the same and the scale gets set to 1.